# How to dump different hash objects into a erb template

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

I have a erb template like this, and i want to dump hash objects into it directly.

```
# test.yml.erb
---
name: <%= name || "bat" %>
director_uuid: <%= uuid %>

release:
  name: bat
  version: <%= release.name || "latest" %>

<%= YAML.dump(compilation) %>

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 3000-90000

<%= YAML.dump(network)%>
```

but i use `ERB.new(test.yml.erb).result(binding)` just get this:
    # test.yml
    ---
    name: bat
    director_uuid: uuid

```
release:
  name: bat
  version: lastest

---
compliaton:
  workers: 1
  network: default    

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 3000-90000

---
networks:
  name: default
```

Is there a way to  remove unneeded `---`?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove that from the dump output of YAML:

```
<%= YAML.dump(compilation).sub(/.*?\n/, '') %>
```